# How to find extension if extension is not in last of a string

Tags: jquery, filenames

I have to get file name. but the problem is that the file name have some appended text after the extension. How can I get only the file name from that string?
like:

```
"636639645944771950download.jpgCreatedOn:06/07/201810:36:35ByShubhamAgawal"
```

In this string I need only file name `636639645944771950download.jpg`.

How can I remove the text that is appended after the extension of the file name?

I tried some thing but nothing is happening.

assume:

```
var abc = "636639645944771950download.jpgCreatedOn:06/07/201810:36:35ByShubhamAgawal"
var s = abc.substring(0, name.indexOf('<br>'));
s = s.trim();
abc = s;
```

Comment: is the text added always like to or it may differ?

Comment: Are there any safe assumptions you can make? Do all of the names have the `CreatedOn` piece appended?

Comment: it may be differ.but format remain same always

Comment: so the file is always image? files will be `jpg`, `jpeg` , `png` ?

Comment: file type is any..text image audio

Comment: how are you getting the text maybe you can fix it by avoiding this kind of string from the way you create it?

Comment: Apply a regex to select the string between "." and "CreatedOn".

Comment: i fix it beacuse i need to show this text below the file name that user showw that who is uploaded file

Comment: can you provide me solution for this @ Roland Weber

Comment: @RolandWeber it will now work since the string might differ

Comment: _“I tried some thing but nothing is happen assume”_ - errors be happening, but you could not be bothered to even check the browser console, is more what I would assume here? There is no variable `name` available in the snippet you have shown, and why you are looking for the position of a `<br>` is also pretty unclear.

Comment: i forget to chnage name variable in code snipper.name is abc on that place

Answer (score 0):

```
if (~abc.indexOf(".")) 
{
 abc= abc.replace(/\s/g, '');
 var s =abc.substring(0, abc.indexOf('Created'));
}
```

Comment: Please don't only post code, but include some explanation (comments) and maybe an example, too.